# how to flip div's css in run time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two div's using bootstrap

```
<div >
<div class="col-md-6">
 this div use the left side of the page  

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
this div use the right side of the page
</div>
</div>
```

it works correctly when I use English language, but my web site use many language as Arabic also, So I need to flip the two div's in run time.
I try to set it an offset class but it useless!

How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you provide me with the css for the divs?

Comment: You should look into `direction: rtl;` and not flip content around.

Comment: if you want to make it professionally then use angular2 , to change css in real time using ng-model etc.

Comment: @McMuffin it has no css !

Comment: @NihalLaliwala I can't use angular2 in this project.

Comment: @colburton Sorry for being summy , I can't understand you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 
   `col-md-6 {direction : 'rtl'; }` 
as for run time you can set it using jquery depend on what you mean by runtime

Comment: I need to get the right div to the left and the left div to the right. and I use it and it didn't work.

Comment: in that case you need to change the layout via css depending on what how you set it up, for example if you are using float you need to float it to the right, post your entire html/css so we can help you

Comment: you're using bootstrap, in this case try:  `.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}`

`<div class="pull-right">elements 2</div>`

Comment: `class="pull-right" ` it is exactly what I need .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to set

```
direction: rtl;  /* Right to Left */
```

or

`direction: ltr;  /* Left to Right */`

based on the language is is being displayed in
To get lang of page

```
var x =  navigator.language; /* Language of the browser */
```

execute on page load

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
#LiveNewsItemTitle0
{
/*  position: absolute;
    left: 270px;
    top : 58px;
    background-size:cover;
    width : 275px;
    height : 105px;*/
    font-size: 11pt;

    z-index: 1;
    direction:rtl;

}
<div id="LiveNewsItemTitle0" class="LiveNewsItemTitle">معلومات الـ"mtv": سلام سيحمل التشكيلة الحكومية إلى</div>
```

use this link for preview: http://fiddle.jshell.net/FKLvy/2/